# Monotone-ness Checking for a two variable function

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a function a function $f$ which is defined on $(0,\infty) \times (0,\infty)$ to $(0,\infty)$ as $$f(x,y)=\frac{px+y}{q+y}$$

Does this function Monotone (Increasing'decreasing) on x and y individually? Here p and q both are positive real numbers.

Help is needed.

Comment: Any restrictions on $p,q$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Thanks. p and q are both positive real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You can view $f(x,y)$ as $\frac{p}{q+y}x+\frac{y}{q+y}$ and $1+\frac{px-q}{q+y}$ respectively.

Comment: So f(x,y) is a non-decreasing in x and a non-increasing in y function, right?

Comment: It depands on the restrictions on $p,q$

Comment: Could you please explain it what kind of restriction I need to put to get the desired one as I mentioned?

Comment: For example, you should discuss $px-q$ whether is bigger than $0$ or equal to $0$ or less than $0$?